# finding top and left values of DIV without setting stylesheet values

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I'm making a drawing application which involves clicking in a div box and reading co-ordinate values. The problem with it so far is that the coordinate values aren't correct relative to the box.

Here's my setup.. the drawing application starts off by loading simple HTML and then a DIV exclusively for drawing. Then I use a click handler to detect a click and return co-ordinates.

The width and height return fine because I defined them for the DIV, but the top and left positions return NaN in javascript.

I know I can easily do this with using css property position="absolute" for the DIV and specifying left and top that way, but that would wreck the rest of the HTML document because then the whole thing would look out of place.

Is there a way I can get a top and left value of DIV without explicitly specifying the two values for the DIV?

I want to achieve this with simple javascript. No jquery.

Comment: Have a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pised/7/edit)**

```
function getXY( ev ){
  var gbc = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      X = ev.clientX - gbc.left,
      Y = ev.clientY - gbc.top;
  alert( X +' '+ Y);
}

document.getElementById('board').onclick = getXY;
```

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.clientX
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.clientY

Comment: I never thought I had to go to the extent of using getBoundingClientRect() to get the coordinates, but thanks.